# How do I make a tooltip div change side depending on what side of the screen it's on? (AngularJS)

Tags: html, css, angularjs, grid, tooltip

I'm using AngularJs to repeat an li numerous times in the form of a grid and I have a description box displaying at the side of each li when I hover over them. But when I hover over the grid items to the right of the grid I want the description box to display on the other side so it does not go off the screen.

Here's a jsfiddle to explain what I mean:

```css
ul {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 5px;
}
li:hover .info {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.image {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}
.info {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <p>Hover over me</p>
    <div class="info">
      <p>Description Here</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <p>Hover over me</p>
    <div class="info">
      <p>Description Here</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <p>Hover over me</p>
    <div class="info">
      <p>Description Here</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <p>Hover over me</p>
    <div class="info">
      <p>Description Here</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <p>Hover over me</p>
    <div class="info">
      <p>Description Here</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <p>Hover over me</p>
    <div class="info">
      <p>Description Here</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <p>Hover over me</p>
    <div class="info">
      <p>Description Here</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <p>Hover over me</p>
    <div class="info">
      <p>Description Here</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My grid also changes depending on screen size so an item on the right hand side will not always be on the right hand side...

Is there any way of changing the grid item class using angular depending on which side of the screen it's on? or any other way of fixing this?

Thanks

Comment: Steal some code from popular open source ui frameworks having a tooltip or dialogue... such as bootstrap, jQuery UI...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would define two classes for the tooltip, one for left and one for right and then use ng-class to call a function. Inside of the function evaluate the position of the element it was called for and return the appropriate class. Below is a fairly complete example that you should be able to apply to your case.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.7/angular-material.min.css" />
    <style>
        .left {
            background: #ff8a80;
        }

        .right {
            background: green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div layout="row" flex="100" ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
        <div flex="50" ng-class="ctrl.getClass('left')" id="left">
            <h1>{{ctrl.hello}} Left</h1></div>
        <div flex="50" ng-class="ctrl.getClass('right')" id="right">
            <h1>{{ctrl.hello}} Right</h1></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js "></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js "></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js "></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.7/angular-material.min.js "></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('app', []).controller("myController",myController);

        function  myController($scope){
            var ctrl = this;
            ctrl.hello ="Hello"
            ctrl.getClass = getClass; 


            function getClass(id) {
                var e=document.getElementById(id);
                var rect = e.getBoundingClientRect()

                if (rect.left < (document.body.clientWidth/2)-1) {
                    return "left"
                }
                return "right"
            }
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you know any way I could evaluate the position of the element?

Comment: BTW, you can ignore the layout stuff I did there with the divs. I just sort of have a starting template that I use as a scratchpad that uses Angular Material, but there's nothing specific to angular material used to determine the object position or class.

Comment: But would the ctrl.getClass('left') no require you to already know what side that div is going to be on? I'd need just like a ctrl.getSide() function which would work out what side it's on a return the appropriate class?

Comment: No. Left is just the ID I assigned to the item as an example. Each item will need a unique ID.

Comment: Oh you're right sorry my mistake! Just tested it there this is perfect thankyou!!